# Getting logs of Openshift applications from Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have a Nodejs server which is used to get the logs of a few servers which are sitting on VMs by connecting to the VM via SSH and using the tail command on the log file.
I wanted to know if there is a similar way or any way to get the logs of an app who's container is on openshift and not a VM, and if there is a way to get the logs of all the pods as one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the OpenShift documentation?

You can install a full EFK stack directly in OCP via an operator and /or forward the logs of everything running in OCP to an external EFK stack
https://docs.okd.io/latest/logging/cluster-logging.html

This works if the logs are written to stdout/stderr in the pods

Here are some other techniques around centralizing logs with kubernetes:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/